# Add hotlink prevention to this php download code

Tags: php, download, hotlinking

How can I add a hotlink prevention to the following code only to be accessed by *.mydomain.com via php? Where do I add it?

```
<?php

$dir = 'folder';

$file = $_GET['name'];

// local file that should be send to the client
$local_file = $dir.'/'.$file;

// filename that the user gets as default
$download_file = 'video.mp4';

// set the download rate limit (=> 20,5 kb/s)
$download_rate = 200;

if(file_exists($local_file) && is_file($local_file)) {

// send headers
header('Cache-control: private');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local_file));
header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$download_file);

// flush content
flush();

// open file stream
$file = fopen($local_file, "r");

while (!feof($file)) {

    // send the current file part to the browser
    print fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024));

    // flush the content to the browser
    flush();

    // sleep one second
    sleep(1);
}

// close file stream
fclose($file);


}
else {
    die('Error: File '.$local_file.' does not exist!');
}

?>
```

I know it must be something like

```
define('HOTLINK_PROTECTION',TRUE); // enable hotlinking?  true/false
define('HOTLINK_PAGE_URL','http://www.mydomain.com/images/hotlink.jpg'); // Hotlink URL
$allowed_domains="*.mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com";

#checks the referer of the script
function getReferer() { preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $match); return $match[1]; }

#checks if referer domain is okay
function hotlink_check() {
global $allowed_domains; $allowed_domains.=','.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$domains=explode(',',str_replace(' ','',$allowed_domains));
$referer=getReferer(); $site=array();
foreach ($domains as $value) { $site[]='^'.str_replace('*','([0-9a-zA-Z]|\-|\_)+',str_replace('.','\.',$value)).'$'; }
foreach ($site as $pattern) { if(eregi($pattern,$referer)) $MATCH=TRUE; if($MATCH==TRUE) break; }
if($MATCH==TRUE) return TRUE; else return FALSE;
}

define('HOTLINK_PASS',hotlink_check());
if(HOTLINK_PROTECTION&&!HOTLINK_PASS&&$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']!='admin') { header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden'); header('Location: '.HOTLINK_PAGE_URL); die(); }
```

But where do I implement it? How can I do that?

--- Edit ---

I did it, but it doensn't work with Mozilla Firefox... With firefox it just goes directly to the hotlink image.

I've tested it with Chrome, Internet Explorer, Safari and Opera and the only one who took me to the hotlinked image was Firefox, I must be doing something wrong here.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

define('HOTLINK_PROTECTION',TRUE); // enable hotlinking?  true/false
define('HOTLINK_PAGE_URL','http://www.site.com/images/hotlink.jpg'); // Hotlink URL
$allowed_domains="*.site.com, www.site.com";

#checks the referer of the script
function getReferer() { preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $match); return $match[1]; }

#checks if referer domain is okay
function hotlink_check() {
global $allowed_domains; $allowed_domains.=','.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$domains=explode(',',str_replace(' ','',$allowed_domains));
$referer=getReferer(); $site=array();
foreach ($domains as $value) { $site[]='^'.str_replace('*','([0-9a-zA-Z]|\-|\_)+',str_replace('.','\.',$value)).'$'; }
foreach ($site as $pattern) { if(eregi($pattern,$referer)) $MATCH=TRUE; if($MATCH==TRUE) break; }
if($MATCH==TRUE) return TRUE; else return FALSE;
}

define('HOTLINK_PASS',hotlink_check());
if(HOTLINK_PROTECTION&&!HOTLINK_PASS) { header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden'); header('Location: '.HOTLINK_PAGE_URL); die(); }

$dir = 'directory';

$video = $_GET['name'];

// local file that should be send to the client
$local_file = $dir.'/'.$video;

// filename that the user gets as default
$download_file = 'video.mp4';

// set the download rate limit (=> 200 kb/s)
$download_rate = 200;

if(file_exists($local_file) && is_file($local_file)) {

// send headers
header('Cache-control: private');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local_file));
header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$download_file);

// flush content
flush();

// open file stream
$file = fopen($local_file, "r");

while (!feof($file)) {

    // send the current file part to the browser
    set_time_limit(0); 
    print fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024));

    // flush the content to the browser
    flush();

    // sleep one second
    sleep(1);
}

// close file stream
fclose($file);


}
else {
    die('Error: File '.$local_file.' does not exist!');
}

?>
```

Comment: Perhaps if you read through the code to figure out how it works, you'd also learn where it needs to be placed.

Comment: don't use HTTP_REFERER, its set by the browser and is totally unreliable

Comment: I tried to add it but it seems not to work, I'm not a php expert. Could any of you please help me to implement this code right? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Dagon what method should I use then?

Comment: as nothing will stop hot-linking with  100% reliability i wouldn't bother. its the nature of the internet, if you put it out there, they will use it.

Comment: hehe yeah, well I just want them not to abuse and consume all my bandwith speed by pulling out my videos into their servers...

Comment: @MarcB thank you for cheering me up to do it myself. But now it goes out of my knowlegde, probably I must been doing something wrong because of the Firefox issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

it was that I used my entire domain name in the file url instead of a relative path..

```
    //download image now 
$file_name = "test.jpg";//$_GET['f'];
$file_url = "http://www.example.com/yfolder/". $file_name; //WRONG
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');    
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 

readfile($file_url);
```

correct code

```
//download image now 
$file_name = "test.jpg";//$_GET['f'];
$file_url = "yfolder/". $file_name; //i removed my domain and it worked,  i managed to download the actual image instead of the hotlinked image
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');    
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 

readfile($file_url);
```